# How to open Command Prompt, change directory and execute a command using Java code (Windows)

Tags: java, command-prompt

The title basically says it all. What I've been able to do so far, by searching around on the web, is the following:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

try {
    Process proc = rt.exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K \"cd " + locaction);
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    //...
}
```

where `location` is the String representation of the directory I'd like to switch to. Not sure if the above is the best way to do that, but either way, how do I then run a certain command from that directory (say, e.g., there's an application there and I want it to run)? Thanks.

Comment: Any specific reason why you want to run from the console?

Comment: The change directory call will not work as expected when using a `Runtime` instance. You should specify the directory as part of the program name.

Comment: @fge : I'm creating an executable jar that makes a directory, puts a certain file there, and then runs a script from that location. The script is best run with a simple command from the command line.

Comment: @Legend : the code ran fine for me. are you saying its just not a preferred way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to run an application with a specific working directory, the easiest way is to use a `ProcessBuilder`:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(executable, arguments, if, any);
pb.directory(theWorkingDirectory);
pb.start();
```